# Custom Wordpress template page upon reload doesn't display any content but source code is all there

Tags: wordpress, browser, reload

Initial load renders all content perfectly and then on the 2nd or 3rd reload (this is random - I've tested this numerous times) it won't display anything on the page except for the nav bar but all the source code loads fine when checking with dev tools and also does not show any errors.

Works fine in Chrome desktop browsers and Firefox desktop browsers - in media view and desktop view.

Doesn't reload on Safari desktop.

Doesn't reload on the following media devices: Android phones, iphone, ipad with Chrome incognito browser and Safari browser.

I am debugging remotely with one of my android devices and I don't see any errors in dev tools and all the source code loads on each reload.

This is hosted on an AWS ec2 instance.

I cannot figure out how and where I need to debug. Any tips/advice is much appreciated!!

Sorry I can't upload image of code or url because this webpage includes info for a live product feature that has not been released to the public yet.

Thank you!!

Comment: @can you show website link so we can check your website at out side at safari browser?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot share website link :( the page has details about a product feature for a live product that has not been released to the public yet. If it helps, the divs and css is all there, ie. if i hover my mouse over the page each div is highlighted and in dev tools computed the css seems fine. I haven't gone over all the css with a fine comb yet though. I was wondering if  this could be a css compatibility across browser issue.. ??

Comment: I can understand your problem. Yes i know that some css is not supported in safari browser so css compatibility issue can be generated by those unsupported css but you can apply alternative css for those css. so I have ask about link because we can see which css property is applying at your web page so we can test and indentify those css which are not compatible.

Comment: I found the problem! There's an outdated plugin call "animsition" that for some reason won't change the opacity from 0 to 1. I just targeted that class and forced css with important tags to just keep the opacity at 1. It breaks the animation but it'll do. Thanks for your time @BhavinThummar :)

Comment: Oh that's good news.